# VBA: "Invalid name for a sheet or chart" error but not on all Excels 365 applications

Tags: excel, vba

The macro works perfectly on mine *Excel365* but it crashes when my colleague runs it on his computer (also *Excel365*). Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'd like to provide the tool working for everyone.

Here's problematic fragment of the code.

```
'Optimalization activated
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


Dim myValue As String
Dim wb As Workbook

'Welcome Prompt/clipboard thingy

    MS = "Hello! Before we start, please prepare Customer ID. We'll need it later" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    MS = MS & "CLICK ON THE 'OK' BUTTON ONCE COPIED"
    MsgBox MS, vbOKOnly, "Welcome - let's prepare Customer ID"


'New excel
    Workbooks.Add
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Data from server - copy & close
    Workbooks.Open ("\\THE_FILE_FROM_SERVER.xlsx")

    Workbooks("THE_FILE_FROM_SERVER").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    Workbooks("THE_FILE_FROM_SERVER.XLSX").Close SaveChanges:=False

'New Workbook magic
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Column cleanup
    Columns("A:C").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:E").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:F").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:K").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("L:Y").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("M:R").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("N:AT").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    
'Borders added
    Columns("A:M").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
    
    
'Top row freeze
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Renaming
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Open Orders Status" & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

The moment it crashes only on some Excels:

```
'Top row freeze
        wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

Thank you in advance for taking a time to review my lines.

Comment: Would guess that the default sheet name is different (it is depending on the language ) and therefore "Sheet1" doesn't exist. Either use the index (`wb.Sheets(1)`) or rename the sheet when you create the workbook. And, of course, obligatory link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/7599798

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas. I'm pretty sure both Excels are in the same language setting. But I'll try indexing and let you know about the effect. About obligatory link - much appreciated hint to improve this aspect. I'm totally self-taught coding impostor and I'm fully aware of this. Have a good one.

Comment: @FunThomas - I've tried indexing the sheet instead of the name and the problem remains (works on mine, crashes on my friends' computers). Also I can confirm that every environment checked was English version of Office 365 inside one company. Do you have any other idea, please?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Activate`-statement throws the error? The error message you wrote in the header ("Invalid name...") suggest it's the next line. And there is the next possible source: `Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")` will format the date according to the regional settings - to be precise it will replace the slash with the regional date separator character. This may be a dot or a slash (or maybe some other characters). A slash is not allowed in a sheet name.

Comment: @FunThomas - indeed that's the cause of the error. On my version **/** was replaced by **-** automatically but for some reason it didn't worked for different Excels. Thank you for your help. I truly appreciate this.